# I've deleted a file I need in the /lib directory. I am struggling to recover that file

Tags: release-freya, applications, software-installation, system, apt

I deleted a file -

> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10

under the false impression that I would be able to easily download a new copy of that file.

The file is needed (I believe) for me to be able to run mongodb shell. When I type 'mongo' to the terminal, I get the error:

> mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In case this isn't clear, I know that this file is not present because I deleted it myself. I now want to get the file back.

Here's a list of methods I've attempted in order to get this file back:

- Downloads through apt-get install. Commonly suggested on other threads/forums for problems with this same 'libssl.so.10' file was a package 'libssl1.0.0'. Unfortunately, that package, nor any other package I've seen/downloaded has replaced the file I deleted. [No 'libssl.so.10' file has been created].
- I've tried to download rpm files (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libssl.so.10()(64bit)) to install this file. Through the sites I've found that offer these, none have supplied files explicitly for Elementary OS. I don't really understand what to do with these files and am concerned that I could make the problem worse by blindly following.
- I've attempted to set-up a dual boot on my rather old laptop, to also run elementary OS, then I thought I could copy the file across. While following this guide: (https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download), the 'rufus' program froze that laptop at the same point three times in a row. I discontinued my attempts.
- I explored using 'testdisk' to recover the deleted file. Given that I deleted the file 2 or 3 days ago at this point and I am concerned about removing making the problem far worse, I didn't want to pursue this.

Can anybody suggest an easier/more successful way I could recover this file?

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you delete it.If it was for any reason I would rename it instead. Never delete important files

Comment: Have you tried my answer.Mark it as answer if it works

Answer (score 4):

Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libssl1.0.0` in the terminal to reinstall the **libssl** library on system

> I recommend before deleting a important file always rename it to `YOURFILENAME.old` or `YOURFILENAME.bak`. Then if you have problems you can always rename it back to the original name :)

So next time don't delete important files like that because you could delete something more important which could cause the OS to be unbootable . If you rename instead of deleting you could always rename it back using the Live USB / CD